# apn_sender and Rails 3

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications, resque

I have a project that needs to send notifications from server to device. I don't know how and where to start (create table first or other), because I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I've follow the apn_sender tutorial but it won't work and always errors out on start. Is there any full tutorial to create apn_sender for Rails 3?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, but I have gotten it working and posted a tutorial as an answer.

Comment: i've done that task for months . Haha . btw , thanks for answering my question . really appreciate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Rails 3 and apn_sender

I too have been working on the apn_sender problem, because I like that the Apple Push Notification support seems pretty robust. However, the project has been abandoned and now it is falling behind the latest 3 series rails. I have gotten the system working as follows.

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'apn_sender', :require => 'apn'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'resque', '1.20.0'
gem 'resque-access_worker_from_job'
```

The signal handling changed in Resque after 1.20 so you must use the older 1.20.0. Daemons should have been a requirement all along but was never explicitly in the gem spec.

#### script/apn_sender

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Daemons sets pwd to /, so we have to explicitly set RAILS_ROOT
RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))

require 'rubygems'
require 'apn'
require 'apn/sender_daemon'

APN::SenderDaemon.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

Retrieved this from [here.](https://gist.github.com/kdonovan/1030667) The reason the apn_sender script is not generated is because the generator script needs to be updated for 3 series rails.

#### Starting the sender

```
./script/apn_sender --environment=production --verbose start
```

When starting the environment the production value is probably what you want since both ad_hoc and release versions are using the production certificate.

[This fork](https://github.com/kdonovan/apn_sender/pull/24) on github has corrected some of the rails 3 issues, but the resque version problem still needs to be resolved explicitly.

#### Manually testing

[This website](http://hansay.com/2012/02/14/using-apn-sender-to-send-push-notifications-to-your-ios-devices/) shows how to send messages bypassing the daemon. He stores the tokens as base64 encoded strings which is nice and compact. The format of a device string in the apn_sender framework is a hex string formatted like this: `deadbeef 0a1b2cdf deadbeef 0a1b2cdf deadbeef 0a1b2cdf deadbeef 0a1b2cdf`. Spaces optional.

```
require 'base64'
ios_device_token = User.where(username: 'Cameron').first.ios_device_token
token = Base64.decode64(ios_device_token).unpack('H*').first.scan(/\w{8}/).join(' ')
notification = APN::Notification.new(token, { alert: 'Hello, World!', sound: true, badge: 99 })
sender = APN::Sender.new(verbose: true, environment: 'production')
sender.send_to_apple(notification)
```

#### Make sure the feedback.rb file is up-to-date

```
# Unpacking code borrowed from http://github.com/jpoz/APNS/blob/master/lib/apns/core.rb
while bunch = socket.read(38)   # Read data from the socket
  f = bunch.strip.unpack('N1n1H140')
  feedback << APN::FeedbackItem.new(Time.at(f[0]), f[2])
end
```

One version of the code lacked 38 and it resulted in bad token strings being returned from the feedback service

#### RubyMine by JetBrains

If you plan on taking Ruby development to the next level you should also consider an IDE like [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) because it makes everything so much easier.